# Changing Data Structure Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do the following scenario:-

```js
var A = ["Jon","Brad","Rachel"];
var B = ["Male","Male","Female"];
var C = [
  {"Jon","Male"},
  {"Brad","Male"},
  {"Rachel","Female"}

]
```

So how to get var C in javascript.

Comment: This is not a sorting. This is a changing on the data structure for the same data.

Comment: Have you tried something on your own first?

Comment: The objects inside C are invalid as those don't have key - value pair in it should be some thing like `{"name": "Jon", "gender": "Male"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to zip two arrays together (not sort); many libraries like Lodash [have methods for this](https://lodash.com/docs#zip).

One way to do it yourself is this:

```
function zip (a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) return [];

    return a.map(function (item, i) {
        return [item, b[i]];
    });
}
```

Note that you've used the syntax `{"Rachel", "Female"}`, which isn't actually JavaScript syntax; arrays like this use square brackets: `[]`. Objects use curly braces `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

I used arrays as the contents, since {"Jon","Male"} isn't valid.

```
var C = A.map(function( name, index ) {
    return [name, B[index]];
});
```

Comment: You can't return an object without creating keys like ppl suggest above.

Comment: Correct, I removed my comment

Answer (score 1):

```
var C = {};
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
   C[A[i]] = B[i];
}
```